# React Context: changeValue function inaccessible while Value *is* accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

The button title from the code below reflects the correct initial value, but attempting to run the changeEvent function results in an error indicating this.props.changeEvent() is undefined. Why is the value readable but not the function? What should I change to fix this?

TestBar:

```
export default class TestBar extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  }

  render() {
    let context = {
      eventPath: this.props.eventPath,
      changeEvent: !!this.props.changeEvent
    }
    console.log("context:", context);
    return (
      <View>
            <Button title={this.props.eventPath} onPress={() => {
              this.props.changeEvent("hello");
              console.log(eventPath);
            }}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

React Context Provider/Consumer definitions:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext();

class EventContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    value: { eventPath: "None", changeEvent: this.changeEvent }
  };

  changeEvent = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: { eventPath: "test", changeEvent: this.changeEvent }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={this.state.value}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { EventContextProvider, Consumer as EventContextConsumer };
```

Excerpt from app page where I'm using the provider and consumer (I'm planning on adding another consumer deeper in the tree once this works)

```
renderContent = () => (
      <EventContextConsumer>
        {({ eventPath, changeEvent }) =>
          <TestBar eventPath={eventPath} changeEvent={changeEvent} />
        }
      </EventContextConsumer>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <EventContextProvider>
            
                <View>
                  {
                    <View style={{
                      elevation: 0,
                      height: 1,
                      width: "100%"
                    }}>
                      <BottomSheet
                        snapPoints={["80%", 65]}
                        style={{

                        }}
                        renderContent={this.renderContent}
                        borderRadius={10}
                        initialSnap={1}
                        ref={this.sheetRef}
                        enabledGestureInteraction={true}
                      />
                    </View>}
          </EventContextProvider>
)
}
```

Comment: `changeEvent` should not be part of `state`. You can directly use that function in provider. Any reason for using like that?

Comment: Why do you recursively refrencing `changeEvent` inside itself.

Comment: what're you trying to achieve with `changeEvent` function